# Water Hammer - Max Pressure Position

Tags: waves, pressure

When using the Joukowsky equation:

**P=cpu**

To find a pressure rise in a pipe due to water hammer. 
How can I find the position along the pipe from the valve closure where the pressure rise is the greatest?

Assumptions are:

- The pipe is straight
- The pipe has a constant diameter, material and stiffness
- Closure of the valve takes t=100ms
- The mass flow consists of air.
- CPU in this case is 343m/s x 1.225kg/m^3 x 1m/s

The pipe has a constant diameter.

My speculations:

- The maximum pressure will be where the wave reflection meets the incoming mass flow and creates a standing wave in the pipe subsequently producing a pressure rise at that position.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have to worry about water hammer if air is going through the pipe.  Air is compressible and is low density, so there will be a much "smoother" and smaller pressure rise in this application than if you were sending a liquid (e.g., water) through the pipe.

Even though pressure rise shouldn't be a problem, expect the pressure pulse from this application to travel from the quickly closed valve, back down the pipe at the speed of sound.  This means that the maximum pressure signal should be seen along the length of the pipe while the pressure is redistributing itself after the valve is closed, which should occur very quickly.

Comment: Hi thanks David. My understanding was that air is treated as an incompressible fluid so would behave much the same as water? Though obviously as air is orders of magnitude less dense than water, the pressure rise would also be orders of magnitude less. 

So if I'm visualizing it correctly; There will be a pressure spike at the valve due to the momentum of the mass flow, the flow will compress, resulting in a maximum pressure rise at the valve which then propagates and dissipates back up along the pipe?

Comment: @CSKB, that is correct.  Regarding the pressure spike, I'll use a physics analogy.  Water in the pipeline is somewhat like a steel cube sliding along a frictionless surface and striking a wall that is in its path.  The cube is stopped very quickly, and large forces result.  Air is like the same cube with a relatively weak spring on the front of it.  The spring compresses when the cube hits the wall, the collision time is extended, and the force is much smaller as a result.  By the way, why would you want to close the valve in 100 ms?  This is faster than most valves can close.

Comment: Quickest way to explain is Water Hammer for propulsion. 100ms would be one cycle of an expand/collapse. So the closing of a valve is an analogue right now.

Comment: Well, if you are propelling a water rocket, you will find that if you use only compressed air, you will get quite a bit less thrust than if you use water and compressed air.  If that is your application, comparing water propulsion with water hammer is probably an invalid comparison.

Comment: It's more based in cavitation, resonance with the surrounding fluid and structuring the pressure differential in and around the device.

Comment: I doubt that a water-hammer approach will adequately deal with cavitation.